# Audio incorrectly outputs to speaker while headphones are in

Tags: iphone, headphones

When I put my headphones in, the music plays, but not through the headphones. I've tried several different pairs of headphones that all work with a different phone. I can't watch or listen to anything with headphones in. It still plays, but it plays through the speakers.

Comment: those headphones holes are notorious for collecting dirt inside.

Comment: @Zach Don't capitalise every word in the title—use normal sentence capitalisation.

Comment: Since it is a title, should it not be in [title-case](http://wordconstructions.com.au/blog/2011/05/what-is-title-case/#sthash.M7EKfUBd.dpbs)? Perhaps there is a meta post? @grgarside

Comment: @Zach [Here's the meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98066/capitalizing-titles)

Answer (score 1):

Try gently cleaning the headphone jack with a toothpick, to clean out all of the dirt and lint.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the headphone jack  (the one in your phone) with a toothpick or other skinny object and if that doesn't work you could take it into an Apple Store.